React: use Ant Design component DatePicker.RangePicker in inline mode
Could you tell me how I can make the DatePicker.ReactPicker dropdown panel with calendars display inline?
i.e. it is necessary that the dropdown calendar is drawn at once and the parent window reacts to its size (increasing or decreasing).
this method:
<DatePicker.RangePicker open={true} onChange={handleChangeDate} />;

fails to produce a suitable result


What does " display inline" means? It's not clear. Please explain

If I understand you correctly you want a single calendar dropdown that switches between from and to instead of the two month view. Afaik there is no such setting in antd. However, you can use the workaround of setting showTime.
